# Banno Transactions Details - HTTP 403

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Able to fetch transactions for all account types successfully other than "Bill Pay". I am seeing an Error - HTTP 403 on the banno transactions endpoint for "Bill Pay" accounts.

```
  URL: /a/consumer/api/v0/users/XXXXXX/accounts/XXXXX/transactions
```

Referring https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/transactions/details/. But this doesn't have any Info about 403 error on transactions endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not expected that an `Account` with `accountType` of Bill Pay would have `Transactions`. Please ignore as that's a hold over from some legacy work.